# Username/Password not working

Tags: passwords, username

There are 5 employees registered to use this database and one of the passwords/usernames is not working.  We were all registered at the same time and everyone else's is working fine.
I have tried contacting our registered agent for support but with no joy.
I hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: You should normally have the option to click on a link at the sigin in screen to  reset your password - this is a little different depending on whether the CMS is Drupal/Wordpress/Joomla but should be there.

Comment: it is disappointing that people such as you are not getting the service you need especially if you are paying a provider.